# Laravel 8 - Force Schema to add primary key in column definition [FIXED]

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am going to create a table with a `char` column as `primary key` and use it on other tables as a reference.
And here is the migration:

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->char('country_id', 2)->index();
    $table->foreign('country_id')->references('id')->on('countries')->onDelete('restrict');
});

Schema::create('countries', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->char('id', 2)->primary();
});
```

Laravel adds index on char columns via `ALTER TABLE` after `CREATE TABLE` as example below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `country_id` CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    ...
) ... ENGINE = INNODB;
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD CONSTRAINT `users_country_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `countries` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT;
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD INDEX `users_country_id_index`(`country_id`);

CREATE TABLE `countries` (
    `id` CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    ...
) ... ENGINE = INNODB;
ALTER TABLE `countries` ADD PRIMARY KEY `countries_id_primary`(`id`);
```

and it's always failing because while creating table `countries`, constraint to `countries.id` already exists and countries table definition must have an index on `id` column otherwise error below:

```
Missing index for constraint 'users_country_id_foreign' in the referenced table 'countries'
```

How can I force Schema to compact index in `id` column definition (not via `ALTER TABLE`) to avoid the error?
as below:

```sql
...
CREATE TABLE `countries` (
    `id` CHAR(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
) ... ENGINE = INNODB;
...
```

**EDIT (FIX):**

As @P.K.Tharindu helped, I just renamed `countries` migration-file to a date before `users` migration file, and Laravel ran it before `users` file.

Comment: Would be useful to show your migrations instead of the database queries.

Comment: @P.K.Tharindu the migration added

Comment: Due to FK constraints, the `countries` table should be created before the `users` table.